# Discord.js V13 Adding Voice Channels to Autocomplete Choices

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a command for a discord bot which opens youtube together. I want to there will be all voice channels in autocomplete choices. How can I add voice channels to autocomplete choices?

```
new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('activity').setDescription('activity').addStringOption(option => option.setName('channel').setDescription("Select channel").setRequired(true).setAutocomplete(true))
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to add channel option not string here `.addStringOption()`
then you need to add `channelTypes`

```js
        description: 'Select channel',
        type: 'CHANNEL',
        channelTypes: ['GUILD_VOICE'],  //or GUILD_TEXT or GUILD_NEWS etc
```

Find more about Application commands [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#options)